# Can't update an object in Redux without overwriting it or losing other items in state

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, reducers

Brief overview..

My state looks like this :

```
isAuthenticated: true

user: {
  avatar: 'avatar.jpg'
  name: 'John Doe'
  username: 'johndoe'
  id: '6dHjStye45fds885'        
}
```

And I'm attempting to only update the `avatar` property with `Redux` in a reducer, but nothing I've tried works as expected. I must be doing it wrong but I just don't know what. I've read as much as I can find on the subject and nothing seems to be working correctly.

If I do this :

```
return {
   ...state,
     user: {
       ...state.user,
       avatar: action.payload
     }
};
```

It wipes out `isAuthenticated` completely and replaces the `user` object with just the avatar, destroying everything else that was in the previous state. I guess I'm wiping out the spread operators with the `avatar: action.payload` ?

And if do this :

```
return {
  ...state,
    ...state.user,
    avatar: action.payload
};
```

It also wipes out `isAuthenticated`, but this time puts all of the user data (including the new `avatar`) at the top level of state (no longer in an object).

Could somebody please show me where I'm going wrong?

**EDIT** adding relevant files

**authReducer.js** (truncated removing non-relevant code)

```
import isEmpty from '../../functions/isEmpty';
import { SET_CURRENT_USER, SET_AVATAR } from '../actionTypes';

const initialState = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  user: {}
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_CURRENT_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: !isEmpty(action.payload),
        user: action.payload
    };
    case SET_AVATAR:
      return {
        ...state,
          user: {
            ...state,
            avatar: action.payload
          }
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**rootReducer.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import authReducer from './reducers/authReducer';
import errorReducer from './reducers/errorReducer';

export default combineReducers({
  auth: authReducer,
  errors: errorReducer
});
```

**store.js**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './rootReducer';

const initialState = {};

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(...middleware),
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
  )
);

export default store;
```

Comment: Please add the full code of the reducer and `createStore` call.
Also try using `combineReducers` https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers

Comment: Okay, give me a sec, and yes I am using combineReducers already..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your code in **authReducer.js** file,

#### from this

```
case SET_AVATAR:
  return {
    ...state,
      user: {
        ...state,
        avatar: action.payload
      }
  };
```

#### to this

```
case SET_AVATAR:
  return {
    ...state,
      user: {
        ...state.user,
        avatar: action.payload
      }
  };
```

#### or this

```
case SET_AVATAR:
  return {
    isAuthenticated: state.isAuthenticated,
    user: {
      ...state.user,
      avatar: action.payload
    },
  };
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing in my original question and it isn't working. The code is different in the authReducer.js file I pasted as I've been trying all different things to make it work. If you re-read my original question you'll see I'm doing exactly what you suggest but it's not working as expected. Am I just going crazy here?

Comment: Scrub that, the last option you provided does work. I was looking at the 'diff' output in DevTools.. Doh! Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score -1):

You need return new object in authReducer.js

```
var newUserObject = Object.assign({}, state.user, {
     avatar: action.payload.avatar   // or some other fields
})

return Object.assign({}, state, {user: newUserObject})
```

Comment: Give me a reason why my answer isn't helpful. If the syntax is not clear, I can explain. The result will be the original object with the modified field. [example](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/object-assign-es6/)

Answer (score -1):

It looks like in **store.js** you are passing the initial state as an empty object. This might be why everything keeps getting wiped out when you use the spread operator.

Try importing default state from wherever you declare it and make an object with all default state to use in `createStore`.

```
import { initialState as authInitialState } from './authReducer.js'
import { initialState as errorInitialState } from './errorRerducer.js'

const initialState = { ...authInitialState, ...errorInitialState };
```

Comment: No this is not the reason, the spread works fine in all of my other functions.  It's just this one function where I'm trying to update a single item in an existing object that is giving me grief.